# HTTP Request options - TypeScript value

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have the following code:

```
export const makeHttpHelper = function (authToken: string) {

  return function ($data: any, optz: object, cb: VoidFn) {

    const data = JSON.stringify($data || '\n');

    const opts : http.Request.options = Object.assign({   /// <<<< here <<<<<<
        method: 'POST',
        host: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || 'localhost',
        port: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || '3040',
        agent: false,
        headers: getHeaders()
      }, optz);

    const req = http.request(opts, function (res) {

      if (res.statusCode > 202) {
        log.error(`res status => ${res.statusMessage}, ${res.statusCode}, req url => ${opts.url || opts.path}`);
      }
      else {
        log.info(`res status => ${res.statusMessage}, ${res.statusCode}, req url => ${opts.url || opts.path}`);
      }

     // ....
});
```

---

....the problem is that `http.Request.options` is not correct. Does anyone know what the right type is for the options object that goes as the first argument to `http.request()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http.Request.options is not correct

Correct one is `http.RequestOptions`.

Fixed :

```
import * as http from 'http';
const options: http.RequestOptions = { // Fixed

}
http.request(options, /* other */)
```